# Efficiently Access numerous Cocoa Controls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I have an interface that has large numbers of controls, see image below.

[Interface http://www.richardstelling.com/hosted/cocoainterface.png](http://www.richardstelling.com/hosted/cocoainterface.png)

What is the best way to access these, creating 288 `IBOutlets` in my `AppController` class and linking them all up seems inefficient.

I looked at forms, but they seemed to simplistic.

This is a proof-of-concept and will not ship so I'm open to any ideas. One caveat however I have to use Objective-C as the final product will be written in Objective-C/Cocoa.

NB:

1. The interface is static
2. Smaller boxed will hold integers (0-255)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) looks like the UI you need. The visual rendering will be a bit different but it will look more 'Mac'.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into [NSMatrix](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is exactly what it's designed to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Either `NSMatrix`, as Rob suggests, or re-think the UI so you have fewer controls on it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could build the entire interface programmatically, with a few lines of code in a loop:

```
const int numRows = 11;
const int rowWidth = 400;
const int rowHeight = 20;
const int itemSpacing = 5;
const int nameFieldWidth = 120;
const int smallFieldWidth = 30;

NSMutableArray * rowList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numRows];

int rowIndex;
NSRect rowFrame = [controlView bounds];
rowFrame.origin.y = rowFrame.size.height - rowHeight;
rowFrame.size.height = rowHeight;
NSRect itemRect
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 11; rowIndex++)
{
    // create a new controller for the current row
    MyRowController * rowController = [[MyRowController alloc] init];
    [rowList addObject:rowController];
    [rowController release];

    // create and link the checkbox
    itemRect = rowFrame;
    itemRect.size.width = 20;
    NSButton * checkBox = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:itemRect];
    [controlView addSubview:checkBox];
    [rowController setCheckBox:checkBox];
    [checkBox release];

    // create and link the name field
    itemRect.origin.x += itemRect.size.width + itemSpacing;
    itemRect.size.width = nameFieldWidth;
    NSTextField * nameField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:itemRect];
    [controlView addSubview:nameField];
    [rowController setNameField:nameField];
    [nameField release];

    // create and link the smaller fields
    itemRect.origin.x += itemRect.size.width + itemSpacing;
    itemRect.size.width = smallFieldWidth;
    NSTextField * smallField_1 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:itemRect];
    [controlView addSubview:smallField_1];
    [rowController setSmallField_1:smallField_1];
    [smallField_1 release];

    //.. continue for each item in a row ..

    // increment the main rectangle for the next loop
    rowFrame.origin.y -= (rowFrame.size.height + itemSpacing);
}
```